# how to download complete genome sequence in biopython entrez.esearch

Tags: python, download, biopython

I have to download only complete genome sequences from NCBI (GenBank(full) format).  I am intrested in 'complete geneome' not 'whole genome'.

my script:

```
from Bio import Entrez
Entrez.email = "asiakXX@wp.pl"
gatunek='Escherichia[ORGN]'
handle = Entrez.esearch(db='nucleotide',
     term=gatunek, property='complete genome' )#title='complete genome[title]')
result = Entrez.read(handle)
```

As a results I get only small fragments of genomes, whith size about 484 bp:

```
LOCUS       NZ_KE350773              484 bp    DNA     linear   CON 23-AUG-2013
DEFINITION  Escherichia coli E1777 genomic scaffold scaffold9_G, whole genome
       shotgun sequence.
```

I know how to do it manually via NCBI web site but it is very time consuming, the query that I use there:

```
escherichia[orgn] AND complete genome[title]
```

and as result I get multiple genomes with sizes range about 5,154,862 bp and this is what I need to do via ENTREZ.esearch.

Answer (score 1):

You've done the hard part and worked out the query,

```
escherichia[orgn] AND complete genome[title]
```

So use that as the search query via Biopython as well!

```
from Bio import Entrez
Entrez.email = "asiakXX@wp.pl"
search_term = "escherichia[orgn] AND complete genome[title]"
handle = Entrez.esearch(db='nucleotide', term=search_term)
result = Entrez.read(handle)
handle.close()
print(result['Count']) # added parenthesis
```

Currently that gives me 140 results, starting with 545778205, which is the same as the website:
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/?term=escherichia%5Borgn%5D+AND+complete+genome%5Btitle%5D

Answer (score 1):

Your question is clear, but the full answer is long. The code I provide generates a .fasta file for each of your desired E.Coli genome sequences, yes only the "***Complete Genomes***" in NCBI.

You will see there are only **six** complete E.Coli reference genomes in NCBI (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genome/167):

[image]

**To help you, here are the Genbank/Refseq links to their genomes:**

1. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NC_000913.3
2. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NC_002695.1
3. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NC_011750.1
4. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NC_011751.1
5. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NC_017634.1
6. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NC_018658.1

**Here is my code for Complete Genome Sequence Parsing into .FASTA files...**

```
# Imports
from Bio import Entrez
from Bio import SeqIO

#############################
# Retrieve NCBI Data Online #
#############################

Entrez.email     = "asiak@wp.pl"             # Always tell NCBI who you are
genomeAccessions = ['NC_000913', 'NC_002695', 'NC_011750', 'NC_011751', 'NC_017634', 'NC_018658']
search           = " ".join(genomeAccessions)
handle           = Entrez.read(Entrez.esearch(db="nucleotide", term=search, retmode="xml"))
genomeIds        = handle['IdList']
records          = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide", id=genomeIds, rettype="gb", retmode="text")

###############################
# Generate Genome Fasta files #
###############################

sequences   = []  # store your sequences in a list
headers     = []  # store genome names in a list (db_xref ids)

for i,record in enumerate(records):

    file_out = open("genBankRecord_"+str(i)+".gb", "w")    # store each genomes .gb in separate files
    file_out.write(record.read())
    file_out.close()

    genomeGenbank   = SeqIO.read("genBankRecord"+str(i)+".gb", "genbank")  # parse in the genbank files
    header         = genome.features[0].qualifiers['db_xref'][0]          # name the genome using db_xfred ID
    sequence       = genome.seq.tostring()                                # obtain genome sequence

    headers.append('>'+header)  # store genome name in list                                     
    sequences.append(sequence)  # store sequence in list

    fasta_out = open("genome"+str(i)+".fasta","w")     # store each genomes .fasta in separate files
    fasta_out.write(header)    # >header ... followed by:
    fasta_out.write(sequence)  # sequence ... 
    fasta_out.close()          # close that .fasta file and move on to next genome
records.close()
```

Let me know how it goes!
Andy

Answer (score 0):

This works for me...

```
search_term = 'escherichia coli[orgn] AND complete genome[title]'
handle = Entrez.esearch(db='nucleotide', term=search_term)
genome_ids = Entrez.read(handle)['IdList']

for genome_id in genome_ids:
    record = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide", id=genome_id, rettype="gb", retmode="text")

    filename = 'generated/genBankRecord_{}.gb'.format(genome_id)
    print('Writing:{}'.format(filename))
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(record.read())
```